# SQL Connection String Error: Object reference not set to an instance of an object

Tags: vb.net, file-upload, oracle10g, sqlconnection

I am trying a version 2 of my file upload question. This time I wanted to test `SqlDbType` versus `OleDbType` without a stored procedure. When testing this example, I get an error

> Object reference not set to an instance of an object

on this line:

```
Dim connection As String = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings("Provider=""****"";user id=" & strUserID & ";data source=" & strDatabase & ";password=" & strPssWd).ConnectionString
```

I don't understand why I get this error (first time using `SqlDbType`)

My table types are as follows:

```
byte: long raw
file_name: varchar2

Protected Sub Insert_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Insert.Click

  Dim extension As String = System.IO.Path.GetExtension(FileUpload1.FileName) ' filename extension
  Dim filePath As String = Server.MapPath("~\") 'shows full path
  Dim fullPath As String = filePath + FileUpload1.FileName 'shows full path plus name
  Dim fileName As String = FileUpload1.FileName

  Dim fs As Stream = FileUpload1.PostedFile.InputStream
  Dim br As New BinaryReader(fs)
  Dim bytes As Byte() = br.ReadBytes(fs.Length)    

  Dim strQuery As String = "INSERT into t_classifieds " & "(addate, category, username, phonenbr, email, description, fulldescription, location, byte, file_name)" _
                               & " values ( val_date, val_category, val_user, val_phone, val_email, val_shortDes, val_longDes, val_location, val_byte, val_name )"

        Dim ClassifiedStr As New SqlCommand(strQuery)
        ClassifiedStr.Parameters.Add("val_date", SqlDbType.Date).Value = DateText.Text
        ClassifiedStr.Parameters.Add("val_category", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = CategoryList.Text
        ClassifiedStr.Parameters.Add("val_user", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = UserText.Text
        ClassifiedStr.Parameters.Add("val_phone", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = PhoneText.Text
        ClassifiedStr.Parameters.Add("val_email", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = EmailText.Text
        ClassifiedStr.Parameters.Add("val_shortDes", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = ShortText.Text
        ClassifiedStr.Parameters.Add("val_longDes", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = longText.Value
        ClassifiedStr.Parameters.Add("val_location", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = LocationText.Text '[8]
        ClassifiedStr.Parameters.Add("val_byte", SqlDbType.Binary).Value = bytes
        ClassifiedStr.Parameters.Add("val_name", SqlDbType.Varchar).Value = fileName
        InsertUpdateData(ClassifiedStr)

End Sub

Private Sub InsertUpdateData(ClassifiedStr As SqlCommand)
    'Throw New NotImplementedException

    Dim connection As String = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings("Provider=""***"";user id=" & strUserID & ";data source=" & strDatabase & ";password=" & strPssWd).ConnectionString

    Dim con As New SqlConnection(connection)

    ClassifiedStr.CommandType = CommandType.Text

    ClassifiedStr.Connection = con

    con.Open()

    ClassifiedStr.ExecuteNonQuery()

    con.Close()

    con.Dispose()
End Sub
```

When I debug line by line I can see it is working:

```
? bytes

{Length=9297}
(0): 137
(1): 80
(2): 78
(3): 71
(4): 13
(5): 10
(6): 26
(7): 10
(8): 0
(9): 0
(10): 0
(11): 13
(12): 73
(13): 72
(14): 68
(15): 82
(16): 0
(17): 0
(18): 2
(19): 176
(20): 0
(21): 0
(22): 0
(23): 128
(24): 8
(25): 2
(26): 0
(27): 0
(28): 0
(29): 124
(30): 195
(31): 205
(32): 101
(33): 0
(34): 0
(35): 0
(36): 9
(37): 112
(38): 72
(39): 89
(40): 115
(41): 0
(42): 0
(43): 14
(44): 196
(45): 0
(46): 0
(47): 14
(48): 196
(49): 1
(50): 149
(51): 43
(52): 14
(53): 27
(54): 0
(55): 0
(56): 0
(57): 7
(58): 116
(59): 73
(60): 77
(61): 69
(62): 7
(63): 223
(64): 6
(65): 23
(66): 12
(67): 49
(68): 40
(69): 151
(70): 192
(71): 200
(72): 240
(73): 0
(74): 0
(75): 0
(76): 7
(77): 116
(78): 69
(79): 88
(80): 116
(81): 65
(82): 117
(83): 116
(84): 104
(85): 111
(86): 114
(87): 0
(88): 169
(89): 174
(90): 204
(91): 72
(92): 0
(93): 0
(94): 0
(95): 12
(96): 116
(97): 69
(98): 88
(99): 116
< More... (The first 100 of 9297 items were displayed.) >
```

Comment: `SqlConnection` and `SqlDbType` are for **Microsoft SQL Server** - not Oracle .... for Oracle, you need to use `OracleConnection` and `OracleDbType` :..

Comment: I was using OleDbConnection but I had issues so I tried to switch to SqlConnection sadly. But I guess I should go back to my past example then

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.configuration.configurationmanager.connectionstrings(v=vs.110).aspx) is an array of strings returned by the system reading your application configuration file (the app.config or web.config). Your connection string should be stored there and given a key property to retrieve it from your application

```
Dim connection As String = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings("myConnection").ConnectionString
```

and in your app.config you need to have these lines

```
<connectionStrings>
  <add name="myConnection" connectionString="user id=xxxx;data source=yyyyyy;password=zzzzzz"
  providerName="System.Data.OracleClient" />
</connectionStrings>
```

Of course this means that your connection string is hard coded in the app.config and thus you can't change it easily at run-time.

A possible alternative is the class [OracleConnectionStringBuilder](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.oracleclient.oracleconnectionstringbuilder(v=vs.110).aspx)

With this class is possible to write a piece of code like this

```
Dim builder As New OracleConnectionStringBuilder
builder("Data Source") = strDatabase 
builder("User ID") = strUserID 
builder("Password") = strPassword
Console.WriteLine(builder.ConnectionString)
```

Comment: I just looked at my web.config and I actually had the connectionString made. I used the name and then my line `Dim con As New SqlConnection(connection)` flagged error `Keyword not supported: 'provider'.` . Don't mean to ask but are you familiar with this issue?

Comment: Not sure what you mean but I will keep researching. Thanks

Comment: I want to say that when pasting your connection string as an example in you my piece of web.config an unnecessary piece of your string slipped in. Now I have removed it and you could test it again without the Provider part. But are you working with Oracle or SqlServer?

Comment: It is oracle. I tried a version of it as you can see at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31162449/file-upload-into-database-and-retrieve but got no where after hours of researching. Didn't realize SQLServer was what I was doing (what is was called). Guess I got to go back to my old version

Comment: If you are working with Oracle then you need to reference the OracleClient libraries and add the appropriate Imports statement to your program. The SqlConnection (and family) are a group of classes used to interact with Sql Server. Oracle has the same classes but prefixed with Oracle instead of Sql. There are two libraries for Oracle (one built in with the Framework and another one coming directly from Oracle with more functionalities) You should choose one or another and (if possible) avoid the generic OleDb classes.